# errors.ts:30 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'products,%20productId'

Tags: angular

I am currently trying to learn a bit Angular by following the tutorial in this website https://angular.io/start/routing

So far, I have everything working fine, up until the section with the routing.

I can access the page directly if I append products/1 to the end of the URL ( this displays the info for Phone XL)
Have compared the code several times with the ones on the website in case there are any typos, but I can't find any

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
BrowserModule,
ReactiveFormsModule,
RouterModule.forRoot([
  { path: '', component: ProductListComponent },
  { path: 'products/:productId', component: ProductDetailsComponent },
])
],
```

**product-list.component.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let product of products; index as productId">
<h3>
<a [title] = "product.name + ' details'" [routerLink]="['/products, productId']">
{{product.name}}
</a>
</h3>
```

**product-details.components.ts**

```
export class ProductDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

product;

constructor(
private route: ActivatedRoute,
) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
       this.product = products[+params.get('productId')];
    });
}
```

The issue I am currently having is that the routing is not working ie clicking on the name of the product, the user is not redirected to the URL
When I inspect the page, I get this error:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes.
>   URL Segment: 'products,%20productId'

Comment: I think you simply have a typo: `this.product = products[params.get('productId')];`

Comment: @Brandon, website has the same. Also tried removing the '+' but that didn't fix it

Comment: @littledevils326 see my answer you have a problem in your routerLink

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to Modify your product-list.component.html as below, [routerLink] take an array of values:

```
<div *ngFor="let product of products; index as productId">
<h3>
<a [title] = "product.name + ' details'" [routerLink]="['products', productId]">
{{product.name}}
</a>
</h3>
```

Comment: tried making the change, still seeing the same error in the console log

Comment: ignore that - that change works. Thanks. Wonder why their website would be telling you to do it differently